# handle relative URLs with Apache ProxyPass

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, relative-path

I've spend two evenings trying to fix this issue. I am using **Apache 2.4** as a **proxy** to redirect connexions to one of my **docker containers** (a simple wordpress, nothing fancy) listening to port 8081.

This conf works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.eu

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, **internal urls** (css files, js, inline href) does not work. Here is an example of

- a failed GET requests for a stylesheet : *http://localhost:8081/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.0.3*
- a successful one: http://domain.eu:8081/wp-admin/

From what I read, this is classical and has been pointed out in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy). Yet, I tried several **known ways around** this issue (redirect subfolders, Substitute, RedirectMatch) but it did not seem to solve this mess. Here are some examples of what I tried

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/js

###### attempt
Substitute "s|http://localhost:8081/|http://domain.eu/wp-includes/|i"

###### attempt
Substitute "s|http://localhost:8081/|http://domain.eu/|i"

###### attempt
RedirectMatch ^/$ /wp-includes/
```

I am not even sure to understand properly how these substitution rules work nor on what they apply (perl based regex + unfamiliar notions for me). Things seems [so easy with Nginx](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-on-ubuntu/). What am I missing? How wold you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it. The trick is to use **location** (not sure why it did not work)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName new_domain.eu
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/

   <Location />
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
        SetOutputFilter proxy-html
        ProxyPassReverse /
        Substitute "s|http://localhost:8081/|https://new_domain.eu/|i"
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    </Location>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/new_domain.eu/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/new_domain.eu/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```